# How to get URL contain only special query string using PHP?

Tags: php, url

For example I have this URL address:

```
https://www.example.com?id=safety&order=1&price=0..995&property[172]=Canasafe
```

I can get query with this:

```
$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']
```

which would output the following

```
id=safety&order=1&price=0..995&property[172]=Canasafe
```

Is it possible I get a query with only for example `price` and `property`?
I want this:

```
?price=0..995&property[172]=Canasafe
```

Comment: @Mohammad No, I do not want turn it in array! also in the question `property is an array`

Comment: @Ali you need to convert it to an array first to get price and prop though.. unless you want to waste some regex

Comment: What keeps you from parsing that URL and building a new one with the parts that it should have?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create an array with the indexes that you're looking for. Use a combination of `parse_str()` and `parse_url()` to get all the elements from your URL, and loop those - select those where they intersect with the `$fetch_elements` array. Then all you need is `http_build_query()` on that array!

```php
$result = [];
$fetch_elements = ['property', 'price'];
$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'] = 'https://www.example.com?id=safety&order=1&price=0..995&property[172]=Canasafe';

parse_str(parse_url($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'], PHP_URL_QUERY), $elements);

foreach ($elements as $k=>$e) {
    if (in_array($k, $fetch_elements)) {
         $result[$k] = $e;
    }
}

echo urldecode(http_build_query($result));
```

- Live demo at https://3v4l.org/RGSGN

Answer (score 1):

You can use regex to get target parts of url in [`preg_match_all()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php)

```
preg_match_all("/price=[^&]+|property\[172\]=[^&]+/", $query, $m);
echo implode("&", $m[0]);
```

Check result in [demo](https://3v4l.org/B50rG)

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can simple use `$_REQUEST`

So to access price you can just use:

```
echo $_REQUEST['price'];
```

Example url

```
http://localhost/test.php?id=safety&order=1&price=0..995&property[172]=Canasafe
```

Output

`0..995`